# YouTube API: follow or subscribe to Playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Given one YouTube playlist ID, I would like to save or subscribe to that playlist and to be added to my library via API.

[playlist added from a channel to my library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omWca.png)

Already checked the API documentation, wondering if I'm missing something.

Thanks

Comment: This is currently not supported. This has been asked in the [google forum](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=6610) and we are yet to hear a response from the Youtube team.